# Handling heavy resources in Spring

Tags: xml, spring

Can anybody tell me what is the best way to handle heavy resources in Spring like I have a configuratio xml file and I am reading it at loading time and keeping it in a static object. 
Everything is working fine but just want to know is there any better option is provided by Spring to manage this kind of scenarios?

Atul

Comment: Could you provide more detail for your requirement?

Comment: I have a xml file which contains some configuration data, right now I am keeping it a static object. Wnat to know any functionality or solution which Spring can provide, so I can use it with Spring. For this scenario I am spring based approach if any available.